# How to set value of checkbox to true using two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, checkbox

I have two arrays

```
Array 1 -> ["Drug", "Kerosene", "Petrol"]
Array 2 -> ["Kerosene", "Drug"]
```

My Array 1 holds all material data & Array 2 is user selected material. So next time when the user opens the form  I want the Array 1 to populate as checkbox & set Elements of Array 2 to true (Check Box Checked) which user has selected

How to achieve this in JavaScript / Typescript ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance. Below is code which populates all checkboxes. I want elements present in array 2 should get checked on load.

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let material of sarr_materialType">
                  <div class="pretty p-svg p-curve" style="font-size:14px">
                    <input type="checkbox" (change)="onSelectMaterialType(material, $event.target.checked)" />
                    <div class="state p-primary">
                      <svg class="svg svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                        <path
                          d="M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z"
                          style="stroke: white;fill:white;"></path>
                      </svg>
                      <label> {{material}}</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Why do you need svg?

Comment: So there will be a list of check boxes for each item in the array 1 and the boxes will be checked if the item exist in array 2. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of arr1">
    <input type="checkbox"  [checked]="arr2.includes(item)">
      {{item}}
</div>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ns9wk9?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks a lot a much simpler solutions :)

Comment: That is exactly what I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by changing your `input` tag to

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="material.checked" (change)="onSelectMaterialType(material, $event.target.checked)" />
```

I am considering that `sarr_materialType` is the array that has all the information that generates the checkboxes. Add a field to your `sarr_materialType` object called checked and set value to it based on whether the content of array 2 exists in array 1. You can use javascript `includes` for that. The ones that are set to true will then be automatically checked.

Answer (score 1):

i used two methods to manipulate checkbox data. may this be helpful.

```
    checked(item){
         if(this.selected.indexOf(item) != -1){
          return true;
         }
    }



// when checkbox change, add/remove the item from the array
  onChange(checked, item){
    if(checked){
    this.selected.push(item);
    } else {
      this.selected.splice(this.selected.indexOf(item), 1)
    }
  }
```

and here is my html

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of options">
      <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange($event.target.checked, item)" [checked]="checked(item)">
      {{item}}
    </div>

    <p  *ngFor="let item of selected"> {{item}}</p>
```

you can check my stackblitz here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly, this will do. The check boxes will be checked if the `material` was found in `selected` array (using `indexOf` function) and upon changing an input, it is either added to `selected` array or removed from it.

```
<div *ngFor="let material of sarr_materialType">
  <input 
    type="checkbox"
    [checked]="selected.indexOf(material)>-1"
    (change)="selected.indexOf(material)>-1 ? selected.splice(selected.indexOf(material),1):selected.push(material)">
    {{material}}
</div>
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k6bm8v